# Filling an outlined circle

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a collection of images with a circle drawn as a white outline. However, I want to fill the complete circle with white color. What is a fast way to do it? The following is the sample of the image:

[image: Sample image]

I have tried using nested loops to achieve this, but it takes a lot of time, and I have around 1.5 million images. The following is my code:

```
roundRobinIndex = 0
new_image = np.zeros((img_w, img_h))
for row in range(540):
    for column in range(800):
        if image[row,column] == 255:
            roundRobinIndex = (roundRobinIndex + 1) % 2
        if roundRobinIndex == 1:
            new_image[row, column] = 255
```

Comment: Have you run into an actual timing issue? Could you show the code that had she problem?

Comment: I'm intrigued - why do you have 1.5 million empty ellipses? :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually these are lung nodule locations stored separately. I want to fill it instead of just outlining it.

Comment: Are they all purely white on black as shown? And what OS are you using?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The code is updated. But it produces artifacts. The answer by nathancy works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried finding the bounding box of the white outline, and getting its centre, then floodfilling with white from there outwards.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2

def findfill(image):
    thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cv2.fillPoly(image, cnts, [255,255,255])

def me(image):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(image)
    cv2.floodFill(image,None,(int(x+w/2),int(y+h/2)),255)
    return image

image = cv2.imread('BLYmz.png', 0)

%timeit findfill(image)
%timeit me(image)
```

This seems to give the same results and run 2.5x faster:

```
findfill
810 µs ± 2.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

me
343 µs ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Of course, if you have 1.5 million to do, I would recommend some parallel processing too :-)

Comment: Of course doing a simple bounding box is much faster than searching for contours. That was bugging me about the accepted answer as well, but I didn't know enough about opencv to say anything :)

Comment: It is indeed much faster. However, I accepted the above answer as it was the only one at the time and it did work faster than my code, without any artifacts.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`cv2.fillPoly()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) to fill the circle contour

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cv2.fillPoly(image, cnts, [255,255,255])

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Note: The Otsu's threshold could be removed for slightly faster performance since the input image is already a binary image, you could directly find contours on the grayscale image

Answer (score 3):

For a truly arbitrary shape, I'd recommend flood fill. However, since you have a guaranteed convex shape, you can make some optimizations. Specifically, every row/column of the image will follow one of three patterns:

1. All black
2. Black, white, black
3. Black, white, black, white, black

Technically there are more options since either or both of the black margins in options 2 and 3 may be missing. The goal is to fill in the middle black region in option 3. This can be done with some simple numpy masking and fancy indexing.

The basic algorithm is:

1. Compute the start index of each white segment
2. Make a row mask of rows containing two start indices
3. Make a full mask containing the original data, with elements between the indices set to `True` as well.

```
def fill_convex(image):
    mask = image.astype(np.bool)
    # mask out elements that are 1, but the previous is 0
    start = (mask[:, 1:] & ~mask[:, :-1])
    # find rows that have exactly two runs of True
    row_mask = (np.count_nonzero(start, axis=1) == 2)
    # get the pairs of column indices that correspond to the masked elements
    cols = np.nonzero(start[row_mask, :])[1].reshape(-1, 2)
    # create a row of column indices the same size as a row
    count = np.arange(image.shape[1])
    # fill in the elements between start and stop indices for each row
    # the None indices are used to trigger broadcasting
    to_fill = ((count[None, :] >= cols[:, 0, None]) & (count[None, :] <= cols[:, 1, None]))
    # update the mask
    mask[row_mask, :] |= to_fill
    # fill in the image
    image[mask] = 255
    return image
```

**Timing**

This method is about twice as slow as [@nathancy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58174534/2988730) and more than 10 times slower than [@MarkSetchell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176593/2988730). I'm basically leaving it here for fun at this point.

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import q58174115' 'q58174115.nathancy(q58174115.image)'
500 loops, best of 5: 437 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import q58174115' 'q58174115.MarkSetchell(q58174115.image.copy())'
5000 loops, best of 5: 62.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import q58174115' 'q58174115.MadPhysicist(q58174115.image.copy())'
500 loops, best of 5: 779 usec per loop
```

Here, `q58174115.py` is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nathancy(image):
    thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cv2.fillPoly(image, cnts, [255,255,255])
    return image

def MarkSetchell(image):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(image)
    cv2.floodFill(image,None,(int(x+w/2),int(y+h/2)),255)
    return image

def MadPhysicist(image):
    mask = image.astype(np.bool)
    # mask out elements that are 1, but the previous is 0
    start = (mask[:, 1:] & ~mask[:, :-1])
    # find rows that have exactly two runs of True
    row_mask = (np.count_nonzero(start, axis=1) == 2)
    # get the pairs of column indices that correspond to the masked elements
    cols = np.nonzero(start[row_mask, :])[1].reshape(-1, 2)
    # create a row of column indices the same size as a row
    count = np.arange(image.shape[1])
    # fill in the elements between start and stop indices for each row
    # the None indices are used to trigger broadcasting
    to_fill = ((count[None, :] >= cols[:, 0, None]) & (count[None, :] <= cols[:, 1, None]))
    # update the mask
    mask[row_mask, :] |= to_fill
    # fill in the image
    image[mask] = 255
    return image

image = cv2.imread('58174115.png', 0)
```

Comment: This is even faster than mine, but I can't read it and don't even know where the answer is to check the results :-) It has my vote though :-)

Comment: @Mark. Thanks for the confidence. I wrote this on mobile with no way to test it. I'll explain and benchmark when I get to a desktop

Comment: @MarkSetchell. I don't think my way is faster :(

Comment: @MadPhysicist, this is some Numpy magic wizardry. I believe my method would be slightly faster if the threshold was removed (since OP's image is already a binary image)

Comment: @nathancy. I suspect that compared to `findContours` the thresholding is quite cheap.